# Writing a voice calling android application?

Tags: android

I am new to android and I would like to write a "Social" android application that would require voice calling between two phones. How should I approach this? Or would it be easier if I "outsource" the voice calling part to another program like Skype?

Thanks!

Comment: when you say voice, do you mean voip or gsm?

Comment: the one that uses data, so voip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick easy solution is to use the [ACTION_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL) intent and use whatever default calling application the user has. If you want to do the whole thing in your app [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/docs/client/android) has a pretty good SDK, but I don't know that I'd recommend getting into that on your first android app..

Comment: Thanks! I am sorry for being a total newbie here, but is Twilio SDK free?

Comment: I don't think they have a free tier, but you should check their site for the most up to date pricing.